# Unable to deploy Swift Vapor app in gCloud

Tags: swift, google-app-engine, gcloud, vapor, server-side-swift

I've a Swift Vapor app which works fine locally. I've tested the endpoints with Postman.

When I try to deploy the app to Google Cloud, I get the following error.

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
>       Application startup error:
>       Fatal error: Error raised at top level:
>
> NIO.ChannelError.connectFailed(NIO.NIOConnectionError(host:
>   "localhost", port: 5432, dnsAError: nil, dnsAAAAError: nil,
>   connectionErrors: [NIO.SingleConnectionFailure(target:
>   [IPv6]localhost/::1:5432, error: connect(descriptor:addr:size:)
>   failed: Cannot assign requested address (errno: 99)),
>   NIO.SingleConnectionFailure(target: [IPv4]localhost/127.0.0.1:5432,
>   error: connection reset (error set): Connection refused (errno:
>   111))])): file
>   /home/buildnode/jenkins/workspace/oss-swift-5.0-package-linux-ubuntu-14_04/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift,
>   line 200

I have no clue what I am missing. This is my dockerfile.

```
FROM ibmcom/swift-ubuntu:latest

LABEL Description="App (swift) running on Docker" Vendor="Imthath" Version="1.0"


# Expose default port for App Engine
EXPOSE 7070

# Add app source
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

# Build release
RUN swift build --configuration release

ENTRYPOINT .build/release/Run
```

This is my app.yaml.

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

What am I missing here? Some google searches with just the error shows that Postgres might be missing. I am using FluentPostgreSQL in my app. In that case, how to install postgres in my container? or what else should I do?

Answer (score 3):

You’re specifying localhost for your Database connection or whatever it is you’re trying to connect to. It’s printed in the error message.

Comment: Thanks. I had earlier mentioned host name as "localhost" in configure.swift file and now I removed it. but I am getting another error -                                                               
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred during deployment.

Comment: No idea. I’d need more info about how you’re deploying and more logs